# Understanding how a TensorFlow model as a class and a TensorFlow Session interact

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, scope, initialization

I have been using TensorFlow for a reasonable length of time now. and believed I had a thorough understanding of how a TensorFlow graph works and executes within a session. However, I have written all of my TensorFlow models in a script-like fashion as such:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import DataWorker
import Constants

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, Constants.sequenceLength, DataWorker.numFeatures])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
xTensors = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)   # [seqLength tensors of shape (batchSize, numFeatures)]

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([Constants.numHidden, 1]))     # Weighted matrix
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))                          # Bias

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(Constants.numHidden, forget_bias=Constants.forgetBias)
outputs, finalState = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell, xTensors, dtype=tf.float32)
# predictions = [tf.add(tf.matmul(output, W), b) for output in outputs]             # List of predictions after each time step
prediction = tf.add(tf.matmul(outputs[-1], W), b)                                   # Prediction after final time step
prediction = tf.tanh(prediction)                                                    # Activation
mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(predictions=prediction, labels=y)                # Mean loss over entire batch
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(1 - (tf.abs(y - prediction) / DataWorker.labelRange))     # Accuracy over entire batch
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(Constants.learningRate).minimize(mse)            # Backpropagation

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # #############################################
    # TRAINING
    # #############################################
    for epoch in range(Constants.numEpochs):
        print("***** EPOCH:", epoch + 1, "*****\n")
        IDPointer, TSPointer = 0, 0         # Pointers to current ID and timestamp
        epochComplete = False
        batchNum = 0
        while not epochComplete:
            batchNum += 1
            batchX, batchY, IDPointer, TSPointer, epochComplete = DataWorker.generateBatch(IDPointer, TSPointer, isTraining=True)
            dict = {x: batchX, y: batchY}
            session.run(optimiser, dict)
            if batchNum % 1000 == 0 or epochComplete:
                batchLoss = session.run(mse, dict)
                batchAccuracy = session.run(accuracy, dict)
                print("Iteration:", batchNum)
                print(batchLoss)
                print(str("%.2f" % (batchAccuracy * 100) + "%\n"))

    # #############################################
    # TESTING
    # #############################################
    testX, testY, _, _, _ = DataWorker.generateBatch(0, 0, isTraining=False)
    testAccuracy = session.run(accuracy, {x: testX, y: testY})
    print("Testing Accuracy:", str("%.2f" % (testAccuracy * 100) + "%"))
```

But now, for practicality and readability, I want to implement my model as a class, but have encountered many problems with initializing my variables, etc.

This is the closest I have got to implementing the above example using my own `LSTM` class

**Model.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import Constants
import DataWorker       # Remove this dependency


class LSTM():
    """docstring."""

    def __init__(self,
                 inputDimensionList,
                 outputDimensionList,
                 numLayers=Constants.numLayers,
                 numHidden=Constants.numHidden,
                 learningRate=Constants.learningRate,
                 forgetBias=Constants.forgetBias
                 ):
        """docstring."""
        self.batchInputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + inputDimensionList)
        self.batchLabels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + outputDimensionList)
        self.weightedMatrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([numHidden] + outputDimensionList))
        self.biasMatrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(outputDimensionList))
        self.cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(numHidden, forget_bias=forgetBias)
        self.numLayers = numLayers
        self.numHidden = numHidden
        self.learningRate = learningRate
        self.forgetBias = forgetBias
        self.batchDict = {}
        self.batchInputTensors = None
        self.batchOutputs = None    # All needed as instance variables?
        self.batchFinalStates = None
        self.batchPredictions = None
        self.batchLoss = None
        self.batchAccuracy = None
        self.initialised = False
        self.session = tf.Session()
        # Take in activation, loss and optimiser FUNCTIONS as args

    def execute(self, command):
        """docstring."""
        return self.session.run(command, self.batchDict)

    def setBatchDict(self, inputs, labels):
        """docstring."""
        self.batchDict = {self.batchInputs: inputs, self.batchLabels: labels}
        self.batchInputTensors = tf.unstack(self.batchInputs, axis=1)

    def processBatch(self):
        """docstring."""
        self.batchOutputs, self.batchFinalState = tf.nn.static_rnn(self.cell, self.batchInputTensors, dtype=tf.float32)
        pred = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(self.batchOutputs[-1], self.weightedMatrix), self.biasMatrix))
        mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(predictions=pred, labels=self.batchLabels)
        optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learningRate).minimize(mse)

        if not self.initialised:
            self.session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            self.initialised = True

        with tf.variable_scope("model") as scope:
            if self.initialised:
                scope.reuse_variables()
            self.execute(optimiser)
            self.batchPredictions = self.execute(pred)
            self.batchLoss = self.execute(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(predictions=self.batchPredictions, labels=self.batchLabels))
            self.batchAccuracy = self.execute(tf.reduce_mean(1 - (tf.abs(self.batchLabels - self.batchPredictions) / DataWorker.labelRange)))
            return self.batchPredictions, self.batchLabels, self.batchLoss, self.batchAccuracy

    def kill(self):
        """docstring."""
        self.session.close()
```

This class is quite messy, especially `processBatch()` as I have just been trying to get it to work before refining it.

I then run my model here:

**Main.py**

```
import DataWorker
import Constants
from Model import LSTM

inputDim = [Constants.sequenceLength, DataWorker.numFeatures]
outputDim = [1]

lstm = LSTM(inputDimensionList=inputDim, outputDimensionList=outputDim)

# #############################################
# TRAINING
# #############################################
for epoch in range(Constants.numEpochs):
    print("***** EPOCH:", epoch + 1, "*****\n")
    IDPointer, TSPointer = 0, 0         # Pointers to current ID and timestamp
    epochComplete = False
    batchNum = 0
    while not epochComplete:
        batchNum += 1
        batchX, batchY, IDPointer, TSPointer, epochComplete = DataWorker.generateBatch(IDPointer, TSPointer, isTraining=True)
        lstm.setBatchDict(batchX, batchY)
        batchPredictions, batchLabels, batchLoss, batchAccuracy = lstm.runBatch()
        if batchNum % 1000 == 0 or epochComplete:
            print("Iteration:", batchNum)
            print("Pred:", batchPredictions[-1], "\tLabel:", batchLabels[-1])
            print("Loss:", batchLoss)
            print("Accuracy:", str("%.2f" % (batchAccuracy * 100) + "%\n"))

# #############################################
# TESTING
# #############################################
testX, testY, _, _, _ = DataWorker.generateBatch(0, 0, isTraining=False)
lstm.setBatchDict(testX, testY)
_, _, _, testAccuracy = lstm.runBatch()
print("Testing Accuracy:", str("%.2f" % (testAccuracy * 100) + "%"))

lstm.kill()
```

A single passthrough of the graph is executed fine, when all the variables are initialized, but it is on the second iteration where I get the error

```
ValueError: Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/Adam/ already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learningRate).minimize(mse)
```

I Googled this problem and learned that using `scope.reuse_variables()` should stop it trying to initialize the AdamOptimizer a second time, but cleary this isn't working how I have implemented it. How can I fix this issue?

As a side note, is my method of creating the TensorFlow session as an instance variable within my `LSTM` class acceptable, or should I create the session in `Main` and then pass it into the `LSTM` instance?

Comment: Try adding the `@property` decorator before your class methods. If it works I will try to write up an explanation for why...if I can figure it out.

Comment: As in literally just write `@property` before each and every class method, or actually define their setters etc. where necessary? Just putting `@property` before each method leads  to a new error `lstm.setBatchDict(batchX, batchY) TypeError: setBatchDict() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'inputs' and 'labels'` when it is called in `Main.py` - which I don't understand as I have never really used Python in any way other that a scripting fashion.

Comment: Hmm...looking at it more I am not sure that would help you. [This](https://gist.github.com/blackecho/3a6e4d512d3aa8aa6cf9) and [this](https://gist.github.com/danijar/61f9226f7ea498abce36187ddaf51ed5) are both great examples of object-oriented TF code that might help. They take different approaches, but I learned a lot from each.

Answer (score 0):

In general I wrap anything that creates variables under the hood with [tf.make_template](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_template) when doing object oriented model building.

However, you should avoid adding ops to the graph in a training loop, which looks like it's happening here. They will build up and cause problems, and likely give you incorrect results. Instead, define the graph (with inputs from tf.data, placeholders, or queues) and only loop over a `session.run` call. Even better, structure your code as an [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators) and this will be enforced.